# How to bind nested array in angular 8 dropdownlist in kendo grid?

Tags: angular, multidimensional-array, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, angular8

How to bind nested array in angular 8 dropdownlist? I want to bind `attrValue` to Value `dropdown` given in image

```
[{
    "ProductID" : 1,
    "Attribute" : "Aspect Ratio",
    "attrValue" : ["1.78","1.85","2.35","2.39","2.40"],
    "Pref" : "true"


}, {
   "ProductID" : 2,
    "Attribute" : "Frame Rate",
    "attrValue" : ["23.98","24","25","29.97"],
    "Pref" : "true"

}, {
    "ProductID" : 3,
    "Attribute" : "Format",
    "attrValue" : ["ProRes"],
    "Pref" : "false"

}, {
    "ProductID" : 4,
    "Attribute" : "Standard",
    "attrValue" : ["HD","HD 1080.23.98 psf","UHD","HDR","UHD SDR","SD"],
    "Pref" : "false"

}, {
    "ProductID" : 5,
    "Attribute" : "Formatted Blacks",
    "attrValue" : ["Yes","No"],
    "Pref" : "true"

}]
```

**Component.ts**

```
public ngOnInit(): void { 
     this.GetCompEditorAreaService.getCompEditorArea().subscribe(data => { 
          this.gridData = data;

    if(this.gridData.length>0){
          this.listAttrVal=[]; 
           for(var i=0;i<this.gridData.length;i++){ 
                this.listAttrVal=this.gridData[i].attrValue;
           }
       }
    });
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<kendo-grid-column field="attrValue" title="Value" width="120">
      <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem let-rowIndex="rowIndex"> 
         <kendo-dropdownlist [data]="listAttrVal [formControl]="formGroup.get('attrValue')"></kendo-dropdownlist> 
     </ng-template> 
</kendo-grid-column>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYOdF.png)

Comment: please show the code which you have tried so far.. that will helps us to understand requirement properly.

Comment: trying to bind data on page load. I want to bind Value dropdown field according to the attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

Kendo-Grid:

**[Kendo-Grid Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kendo-datagrid-example-xi3qcp?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

```
<kendo-grid [data]="data" [height]="370">
    <kendo-grid-column field="Attribute" title="Attribute" width="40">
    </kendo-grid-column>

    <kendo-grid-column field="UnitsInStock" title="In stock" width="80">
        <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
            <select >
               <option *ngFor="let x of dataItem.attrValue" [value]="x" >{{x}}</option>
            </select>
        </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="Pref" title="Pref" width="120">
        <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
            <input type="checkbox" [checked]="dataItem.Pref" />
        </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-column>

</kendo-grid>
```

HTML Table:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-blvh7d?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

```
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of data;let i = index">
        <td>
            {{item.Attribute}}
        </td>
        <td>
            <select [(ngModel)]="item.value">
                <option *ngFor="let x of item.attrValue" [value]="x" >{{x}}                              </option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox"  [(ngModel)]="item.Pref" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm using kendo grid. I want to bind value to kendo dropdown list

Comment: You didn't mention about kendo-grid in your question

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning. Please help me with this

Comment: Check kendo grid demo

Comment: checked...no solution for multidimensional array

Comment: Your question was binding nested array i.e `"attrValue" : ["23.98","24","25","29.97"]` in dropdown item, its working in the demo

Comment: Is your problem solved? If not, you can explain it a bit more

Answer (score 0):

A better kendo way of performing dropdown operations is this :

```
<kendo-grid-column [headerClass]="{'kendoColumn': true}" field="cDiv" title="Division"
        width="90">
          <ng-template kendoGridEditTemplate let-dataItem="dataItem">
            <kendo-dropdownlist [data]="divList" textField="name" valueField="id"></kendo-dropdownlist>
          </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```